# A problem with webpage to close and reopen the tab IE 11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I am getting a problem in react application. On ***window.location = "url"*** the IE closes the dev tool if opened and refresh the same page by showing the dialogue message "A problem with webpage to close and reopen the tab". Even if I do ***window.location = "any other site url"*** and also for ***window.location.href***.

Sometime it redirect me to res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm#,

Browser = IE 11
OS Windows 10

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to make a test in simple HTML file to check whether it gives similar results or not. It can help to know whether anything is related with your React app or not. For testing purpose, try window.location.assign(). I also suggest you to run the same code on any other machine with IE 11 to check whether it is machine specific issue or not. If it can only occur on your machine then try to reset your IE browser and again make a test. I tested it on my side and it works fine with IE 11 Windows 10. Let us know about your testing results.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding leading slash
window.location.assign('/test.php');

Comment: with window.location.assign('/test.php'); it is taking me to res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm#<host>, <current url>

Happening with all machine, event if I reload the page same problem happen.

Comment: Can you provide a sample code which can produce the issue? On our side it is working fine or may be we are missing something. If you can provide any sample which can help to reproduce the issue then it can help us to understand the issue properly. Thanks for your understanding.